# Intent request times out when accessing Firebase's firestore database within Alexa

Tags: node.js, firebase, alexa-skills-kit

I have the following code (that is relevant):

```
 let cSay = `The stock for warehouse ${slotValues.number.heardAs} is `;
        let whStock = 0
        whStock = await getWarehouseStock(slotValues.number.heardAs);
        console.log('WH STOCK------------>', whStock);
        cSay += whStock;
        return responseBuilder
            .speak(cSay)
            .reprompt('try again, ' + say)
            .getResponse();
    },
```

And the getWarehouseStock function:

```
const getWarehouseStock = async (whNumber) => {
    console.log('WH Number--------------> ', whNumber);
    const warehousesRef = firebase.firestore().collection('warehouses');
     
    const snapshot = await warehousesRef.get();
    const warehouses = [];
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
        warehouses.push(doc.data());
    });
    let whStock = 0;
    if ('products' in warehouses[whNumber-1]) {
        console.log('WH INFO--------------> ', warehouses[whNumber-1]);
        whStock = Object.keys(warehouses[whNumber-1].products).length;
    }
    console.log('WH Stock--------------> ', whStock);
    return whStock;
}
```

The last console log before `return responseBuilder` triggers correctly with the right info. I can can the data from the firestore, but the problem is that alexa times out after like 8 seconds. Why does this happen ? or how can I fix the timeout thing

Answer (score 0):

The 8 second timeout is a default feature on Alexa Service.

> The Alexa Service timeout is 8 seconds, so make sure you get a response back from Lambda before Alexa times out.
> [*Source*](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/546ab5a1-1d1a-49c2-85a5-92ada3e6e907/best-practices-for-scaling-your-alexa-skill-using-amazon-web-services)

You can't change it. You have to give a response within 8sec.
You should also check [ProgressiveResponse](https://developer.amazon.com/en-GB/docs/alexa/custom-skills/send-the-user-a-progressive-response.html), which allow you to `keep the user engaged while your skill prepares a full response to the user's request` if it make sense in your skill.

Comment: but the thing is that the code reaches the return of the intent handler. In less than 8 seconds. The problem is that the the firebase keeps the connection open for 300 seconds, even tho it gives you the needed info in 1 second. I tried app.initialize() and app.delete() after I get the info, but it didn't work

Comment: Does the Alexa skill says anything after receiving the response? Can you provide more details? –